# How automatic apple tv setup works

Tags: ios, tvos, apple-tv

I just got the new Apple TV and it has a really cool feature that allows you to set it up by simply placing your phone close to the Apple TV box. It's clear that it works through Bluetooth, but how exactly? Are there any SDKs available for AppleTV OS and/ or OSX to capture unique apple devices in the area?

Comment: Do research on "Bonjour".